# MYSQL COUNT(*) for every row

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables in my DB. First is `category` (categorytbl)

```
Category
ID | Category
```

Second is for `items` (itemstbl)

```
Items
id | ItemName | CategoryID | Date | Description
```

Now i need to select and count `COUNT(*)` all Items from `categoryID` but I have problem because I can put one item  in more than one category

So, when I make list of all categories I need to know how many items I have in every category

category 
SUV (4 items)

Offroad (43 items)

for example

I have item 
CAR -> i can put car into SUV, Luxury, Offroad...

thx for helping

Comment: If an item can have multiple categories, then you datamodel is wrong.. you're modeling a 1xN relationship, when it should be NxN (e.g. one item belongs to many categories; and you can find many items in one category)

Comment: whats your suggestion than?
Cos i have a lot of categories and every category can have a lot of items and every item could have more than one category

Comment: [Many-to-Many Design](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) . Create an itermediary table `items_categories` where the PK is the `item_id` and the `category_id` (both are also FK), the Count query should be as simple as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items_categories WHERE category_id=123`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id, c.category, count(c.id) as cat_count
FROM items i
INNER JOIN category c ON (i.category_id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 SELECT Category, count(*) from Category as c, Items as i
 WHERE c.ID = i.CategoryID
 GROUP BY Category
 ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: I have problem with my items CategoryID cos in that field i have more than one category 1,44,22,55 sepparated with comma so how i got all data from that field

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the comments, it sounds like you need to refactor your data model because you want a many-to-many (M to N) relationship between items and categories, whereas you have data that's not in 1NF (since it's comma-separated).

This can be accomplished using an intersection table (also known as a junction table:  [here's a Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)).

To count the number of categories for each item (that has at least 1 category):

```
SELECT item_id, count(*) 
FROM junction_table
GROUP BY item_id
```

And to count the number of items for each category (that has at least 1 item):

```
SELECT category_id, count(*) 
FROM junction_table
GROUP BY category_id
```

If you wanted to also include items/categories for which there were no categories/items, you could `LEFT JOIN` to the appropriate table.